# What's the runtime complexity of this code which contains four recursive calls?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

what's its run-time complexity which has 4 recursive functions.

```
def func(arr,i,j,N):

  if i==N or j==N or i<0 or j<0: 
     return
  if arr[i][j]==1 or arr[i][j]=='X': 
     return

  arr[i][j]='X' 

  func(arr,i,j+1,N) 
  func(arr,i,j-1,N) 
  func(arr,i+1,j,N) 
  func(arr,i-1,j,N) 

  return(arr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a data-analytical approach first. We can try running the function with smaller Ns and look for a pattern.

```
import numpy as np


global call_cnt

def cc(arr,i,j,N):

  global call_cnt

  call_cnt += 1
  #print(call_cnt)

  if i==N or j==N or i<0 or j<0:
     return
  if arr[i][j]==1 or arr[i][j]=='X':
     return

  arr[i][j]='X'

  cc(arr,i,j+1,N)
  cc(arr,i,j-1,N)
  cc(arr,i+1,j,N)
  cc(arr,i-1,j,N)

  return(arr)


n_On = []

for i in range(1,30):
  global call_cnt

  call_cnt = 0

  cc(np.zeros((i,i)).tolist(), 0, 0, i)

  print(call_cnt)
  n_On.append(call_cnt)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(n_On)
plt.show()
```

1. We have initialized the arrays with non-1 values so that we don't meet the base case arr[i][j] == 1, so the program will run for the worst-case scenario.
2. After 29, we get a maximum recursion depth, so we just chose 1-29 for our N.
3. After plotting the number of total calls for each N, we get this plot.

```
5
17
37
65
101
145
197
257
325
401
485
577
677
785
901
1025
1157
1297
1445
1601
1765
1937
2117
2305
2501
2705
2917
3137
3365
```

[image: N vs number of calls]

Now, we can fit these points using many regression lines, one thing is for sure it's not exponential.

After a little bit of tuning with numbers, you can see the function `4xN^2` is very close to it, in fact, the values perfectly fit `4xN^2 + 1` function.

Let's try to plot this function on top of the number of calls.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(n_On)
plt.plot([4*(i**2) + 1 for i in range(1,30)], 'k+')
plt.xlabel('N')
plt.ylabel('number of calls')
plt.show()
```

[image: N vs number of calls]

It's a perfect fit!

Now, why? In your recursive function, you have mainly 2 variables that are changing i and j. As i and j are only changing in range N (due to your check i, j > 0 and i, j < N) (ixj -> NxN -> N^2) and you also did use memoization (not visiting already visited cells), so here's N^2 possibility in total.

Finally, there are 4 calls for each case. Hence, this complexity.

So, it's `O(N^2)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was think that it would be N^2 but wasn't able to conclude because of lack of proof!

Answer (score 0):

It's O(N^2). Each cell is visited at most once from each of its neighbours, so there's at most 4N(N-1) function calls (excluding those which go out of bounds, of which there's at most 4N). You can add a counter that's incremented each time `func` is called to check.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the grid as a graph with the grid points as vertices and the edges being the line segments between adjacent points of the grid.

the number of nodes is `N^2` and you visit each one of them, so the algorithm is necessarily `\Theta(N^2)`. In doing so you follow each edge exactly once (After the first visit to an edge, both endpoints are marked `1` or `X`, so for none of the end points the program flow will ever again reach the recursive calls).

The number of edges is `2N(N-1)`. Thus the algo runs in `O(N^2)`.